# Django filtering with F and Q operations

Tags: django

I have a model class in my django project:

```
*user_id
*amount
*net_balance
*created_on
```

I have a list of user_ids(let's say 3). I need to get the last row for each user_id and then do some operation and create a new row for each user id. How do this efficiently. I can certainly do 6 transactions (if there are 3 items in list of userids).

Comment: What do you mean with the last row? There is no last row in a database, the concept of an order based on insertion is actually non-existing (in most database systems).

Comment: By last row, I mean the latest entry for that particular user. There is a date field also, hence we can get the latest entry existent in the db for that user

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent entry then

```
YourModel.objects.filter(user=user_id).latest('created_on')
```

If I understand your question correctly then you need to get all the user_ids (presumably you have a separate User model?) and then loop through them - for each user getting the most recent entry and then create the new row.

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 select (at least) for all the records you interested and 1 insert query for each record returned.
The select query can be generated by ORM abilities (aggregation) or you can use raw SQL if you fill comfortable. If you use PostgreSQL, you can use **distinct** ability (I recommended) as:

```
Model.objects.order_by('user_id', '-created_on').distinct('user_id')
```

or you can use aggregation abilities as:

```
Model.objects.filter(user_id__in=[1,2,3]).values('user_id', 'created_on').annotate(last_row=Max('created_on')).filter(created_on=F('last_row'))
```

The correct answer depends on your Django version and database. But there are lots of good features in Django to achieve this kind of stuffs.